# How to move object based on its angle?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am using Unity3d with mono develop(c#).

My object is Arrow.It gets Random Angel at starting.When i click on arrow ,it should be move like gun shooting some Point.How to achieve this?can any one help?

Comment: Link-signature removed. Please read the policy on signatures: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/52486/171662 and the last paragraph (Avoid overt self-promotion) here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior

Comment: Sorry, I meant the 2nd to last paragraph: "Do not use signature, taglines, or greetings."

Answer (score 0):

The `forward` Vector3 on the [Transform](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-forward.html) belonging to your GameObject describes which direction is forward for the object.

An example given on the linked page is `rigidbody.velocity = transform.forward * 10;`. So if you were to put that line of code in your `FixedUpdate` function then your GameObject would move forward at a velocity of 10 * framerate.